# Javascript function not going to the next list on second try

Tags: javascript, html, list, function

I have problem with my javascript function. It is not working as expected. Look at this fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/NM3k6/1/ .**

Here I have questions with three selection each. If you select and answer through the normal flow. It will give you both the 2 correct answer. Now here is my problem, After you answer the first question, navigate back to first question again and select answer. It will right away show result without going to the next question.

Below is the code.

```
<center>
<div id="your-curve-id">
  <fieldset class="questions" style="border: 1px solid #000; width:500px; margin: 20px">
    <h2 id="p1">1. Please select your Curve Id 1</h2>
    <ul id="ul1">
      <li class="option" name="Curve Id 1" value='Select 1A'>Answer 1</li>
      <li class="option" name="Curve Id 1" value='Select 1B'>Answer 2</li>
      <li class="option" name="Curve Id 1" value='Select 1C'>Answer 3</li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="questions" style="border: 1px solid #000; width:500px; margin: 20px">
    <h2 id="p2">2. Please select your Curve Id 2</h2>
    <ul id="ul2">
      <li class="option" name="Curve Id 2" value='Select 2A'>Answer 1</li>
      <li class="option" name="Curve Id 2" value='Select 2B'>Answer 2</li>
      <li class="option" name="Curve Id 2" value='Select 2C'>Answer 3</li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</div>
</center>
<div id="results"></div>
```

here's the script..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    answers = new Object();
    var totalQuestions = $('.questions').size();

    $('.option').click(function(){
        console.log($(this).attr('value'));
        var answer = ($(this).attr('value'));
        var question = ($(this).attr('name'));
        answers[question] = answer;
        $('#count').html(Object.keys(answers).length + " / " + totalQuestions);
        next();
        back();
    });

    var currentQuestion = 0;
    $questions = $('.questions');
    $('ul#ul2').hide();

    function next(){
        $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).ready(function(){
            currentQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;
            if(currentQuestion == totalQuestions){
                //do stuff with the result
                var result = values();
                $('div#your-curve-id').hide();
                $('#results').html(result);

            }else{
                $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).show();
                $('ul#ul1').hide();
                $('ul#ul2').show('slow');
            }
        }); 
    }

    function values(){
        var res = "";
        var imahe = "";
        for (questions in answers)
        {
            if (answers.hasOwnProperty(questions)) {
                res += questions + '::' + answers[questions] + '<br />' + '<br />';
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    function back(){
        $('h2#p1').click(function() {
            $('ul#ul1').show('slow');
            $('ul#ul2').hide();
        });
    }
});
```

Look at this fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/NM3k6/1/ .**

Comment: Why do you use `.ready()` in `next()`?

Comment: basically to execute when document is ready. should i use something else?

Comment: the thing is after I goes back to the first question and select answer.. the result show right away without getting to the next question.

Comment: The entire code is in the document.ready handler, why do you think you have to do it again in a function that will only be called after that?

Comment: I know what the thing is, you explained it clearly in the question, and I can see it happening in the fiddle.

Comment: When the user goes back, you don't decrement `currentQuestion`. So when they answer question 1 a second time, you add 1 to `currentQuestion`, and then it equals `totalQuestions`.

Comment: i take that out and gives the same result.

Comment: There's nothing to take out.

Comment: Thank you Barmar. Appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reduce `currentQuestion` when the user goes back:

```
function back(){
    $('h2#p1').click(function() {
        currentQuestion--;
        $('ul#ul1').show('slow');
        $('ul#ul2').hide();
    });
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/NM3k6/2/)

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: you increment `currentQuestion` in `next()`, but you never decrement it in `back()`.

```
  function back() {
    $('h2#p1').click(function() {
      currentQuestion--;
      $('ul#ul1').show('slow');
      $('ul#ul2').hide();
    });
  }
```

For a *much* better answer, though, I suggest that you submit the same question, with that fix applied, to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).